# How do you say "to brown-bag it" in your neck of the woods?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary, dialects, dictionaries, world-english

Is the North American phrase "to brown-bag it"--which means to take a packed lunch to work, school, etc.--used or at least readily understood in the UK and other English-speaking countries? How would you say this in the variety of English you speak?

Comment: From wikipedia (redirected from *brownbag*, superscripts deleted): [*A **packed lunch** (also called **pack lunch**, **sack lunch** or **bag lunch** in North America, or **pack up** in the United Kingdom, as well as the regional variations: **bagging** in Lancashire, Merseyside and Yorkshire,) is a lunch prepared at home and carried to be eaten somewhere else, such as school, a workplace, or at an outing.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packed_lunch)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was wondering if there were other one-word verbs for it.

Comment: The standard expression in the UK is "packed lunched".

Comment: In my experience 'brown-bag it' isn't used in the UK, people would probably understand it given enough context, or they could be familiar with it from exposure to US media. I know it from reading 'Peanuts' 40 years ago, so would have assumed it was now dated.

Comment: I (UK) would say 'take a packed lunch' or 'take sandwiches'.

Comment: @BillJ - Not sure if you're joking, have been mishearing for years, made a typographical error, or genuinely know a wide range of people who would call it a "lunch**ed**"... but everyone I've met across south east England refers to it as a "packed lunch".

Comment: @AndyT Whoops! Should be "packed lunch", of course. Apologies for the typo.

Comment: One of the quirky but presumably important distinctions between US American and British English is we don't have a true equivalent to *to brown-bag it* in most of Britain, anyway. Yes, *what* we take is a *packed lunch* but that's the subject, not the verb or the phrasing we apply to it.
Many Brits will understand *brown-bag it* and does anyone doubt, many others will take that to mean put the left-overs from a restaurant meal in a *doggy bag*. Without context, don't we think many might hear it meaning to use the brown bag as a pooper scooper?